# How to draw a line in SpriteKit efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, line-drawing

In my SpriteKit scene, user should be able to draw line with his/her finger. I have a working solution, if the line is long, FPS gets down to 4-6 and the line starts to get polygonal, as the image below:

[image]

To draw `myline` (`SKShapeNode*`), I collect points of touches movement in an `NSMutableArray* noteLinePoints` in this way

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self.scene];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchPoint];

    if(noteWritingActive)
    {
        [noteLinePoints removeAllObjects];
        touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:_background];
        [noteLinePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
        myline = (SKShapeNode*)node;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(myline)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:_background];
        [noteLinePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
        [self drawCurrentNoteLine];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(myline)
    {
        myline.name = @"note";
        myline = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"touch ended");
}
```

and I draw the line in this way

```
- (CGPathRef)createPathOfCurrentNoteLine
{
    CGMutablePathRef ref = CGPathCreateMutable();

    for(int i = 0; i < [noteLinePoints count]; ++i)
    {
        CGPoint p = [noteLinePoints[i] CGPointValue];
        if(i == 0)
        {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(ref, NULL, p.x, p.y);
        }
        else
        {
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, NULL, p.x, p.y);
        }
    }

    return ref;
}

- (void)drawCurrentNoteLine
{
    if(myline)
    {
        SKNode* oldLine = [self childNodeWithName:@"line"];
        if(oldLine)
            [self removeChildrenInArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oldLine]];

        myline = nil;

        myline = [SKShapeNode node];
        myline.name = @"line";
        [myline setStrokeColor:[SKColor grayColor]];

        CGPathRef path = [self createPathOfCurrentNoteLine];
        myline.path = path;
        CGPathRelease(path);

        [_background addChild:myline];
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem? because all subsequent lines are all polygonal only, I think because the fps is very low and sampling rate of touches automatically get also very low...

Please note that for the test I used an iPad 3 (my app needs to be working from iPad 2 model with iOS7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not constantly create new `SKShapeNodes`, there is a bug which is causing your slowdown.  Instead, only use 1 `SKShapeNode` (Or create a bunch but reuse them), and append the path with new info  (So there is no need to constantly add the myline to the background)

Alternative:

Use 1 community `SKSkapeNode` for rendering of the path,  then convert the `SKShapeNode` to a texture with `view.textureFromNode`, then add an `SKSpriteNode` with this new texture instead of the shape node

Comment: my user should be able to draw as much lines as he/she desire, anyway I'll try to reuse always the same SKShapeNode. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: NP, maybe they will fix SKShapeNodes in iOS 10

Comment: @ddb  I posted an alternative answer that may work out better for you

Comment: well, I forgot to mention in my question that my app needs to work from models iPad2 with iOS7... I'm not very lucky...

Comment: it's a commercial app, they will not do it

Comment: Man, they want to support those 1% of people lol  I guess you may be updating an older app.  Anyway iOS 7s version of Sprite Kit is riddled with bugs, so good luck managing it.